# Jquery .submit not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on ajax.
Browser is google chrome.
Instead of alerting ok when i click on submit, my browser submits the form.
What's wrong here?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cp/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    $("#test").submit(function(){
    //$.post("test.php", this.serialize());
    alert('ok');
    return false;
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="test">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form is not defined yet when the script is executed. Wrap it in a [`$().ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").submit(function() {
    //$.post("test.php", this.serialize());
    alert('ok');
    return false;
    });
});
```

I can see the following question coming: "What not defined?".
Yes:

```
...
# Hey, a script tag, let's wait, and load the resource.
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cp/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

# Hey a script tag!
<script language="javascript">
$("#test").submit(function(){
//$.post("test.php", this.serialize());
alert('ok');
return false;
});
</script>
# The script block has ended, let's parse the script
# ... *calls* $('#test'). ....

# Now, #test is defined. Too late...
<form id="test">
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the function is being executed on `document.ready`, and then don't forget to prevent the default behavior for the `submit` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('ok');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Tested on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in Chrome.

Comment: @HardeepBrah - Great, I'm glad to hear it. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful to you.